# Can't disable Hyper-V in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

While developing Android apps with Xamarin in Visual Studio 2019, I am experiencing problems with the android emulators, so, following a couple of posts online, I am trying to enable HAXM in order to fix my issues. In order to do so, I need to disable hyper-v.

I have unchecked all the boxes about Hyper-V in windows features.
Used DG_Readiness_Tool script to disable it `PS D:\DownloadsFirefox\dgreadiness_v3.6> .\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable`
Also, uninstalled my VPN and Oracle VM network drivers, but to no avail.

Every time I run DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 script, I get the same output:

```
###########################################################################
Readiness Tool Version 3.4 Release.
Tool to check if your device is capable to run Device Guard and Credential Guard.
###########################################################################
Disabling Device Guard and Credential Guard
Deleting RegKeys to disable DG/CG
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
del : Cannot find path 'C:\Windows\System32\CodeIntegrity\SIPolicy.p7b' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ del  "$env:windir\System32\CodeIntegrity\SIPolicy.p7b"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Windows\Syst...ty\SIPolicy.p7b:String) [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Disabling Hyper-V and IOMMU
Disabling Hyper-V and IOMMU successful

Please reboot the machine, for settings to be applied.
```

After that I reboot and get a messages weather I want to confirm disabling Device Guard and Credential Guard. Then my windows starts, I run the checktool and here we go, Hyper-v is not disabled.

```
PS D:\DownloadsFirefox\checktool-windows-1.0.0> .\checktool.exe --verbose
CPU vendor          *  GenuineIntel
Intel64 supported   *  Yes
VMX supported       -  No
VMX enabled         -  No
EPT supported       -  No
NX supported        *  Yes
NX enabled          *  Yes
Hyper-V disabled    -  No
OS version          *  Windows 10.0.18363
OS architecture     *  x86_64
Guest unoccupied    *  Yes. 0 guest(s)
```

Comment: IIRC the most recent Android emulator included with Visual Studio is based on Hyper-V, so maybe you could use that. See here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you can try disable Hyper-v via Command Prompt and PowerShell

Right-click on **Windows key** and select **Command Prompt (Admin)**.

Copy and paste the **Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth**. Press **Enter**.

Then run the **Dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup** command and hit **Enter**.

Now type the **sfc /scannow** and press **Enter** again.

Close Command Prompt and open **Windows PowerShell**(with administrative privileges).

Type **PowerShell** in Windows search, right-click it, and select **Run as Administrator**.

Copy and paste the **Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All**.

Close PowerShell and reboot the PC.

Reference:
https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-10/

Comment: Done all. The results are absolutely the same as before. On restart I'm asked wether to disable Device Guard and Credential Guard. Then, when I run the checktool the result is the same as before